# How to create todoist task using todoist api v7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, asynchronous, todoist

I'm trying to create a task in todoist but cant seem to do so

According to this [todoist documentation](https://developer.todoist.com/sync/v7/#add-two-new-tasks), the below should work for creating a todoist task

```
$ curl https://todoist.com/api/v7/sync \
    -d token=0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567 \
    -d sync_token="VRyFHr0Qo3Hr--pzINyT6nax4vW7X2YG5RQlw3lB-6eYOPbSZVJepa62EVhO" \
    -d resource_types='["projects", "items"]' \
    -d commands='[
        { "type": "item_add",
          "temp_id": "fdef5d16-a40a-475e-bd4a-0ccbd6fd8c3f",
          "uuid": "a3aa2f44-23b4-4986-b513-ef7663bbb752",
          "args": { "project_id": "24a193a7-46f7-4314-b984-27b707bd2331", "content": "Task1" } },
        { "type": "item_add",
          "temp_id": "6f5e0b50-af7a-4133-bfc0-e8c041b819d2",
          "uuid": "d16ad84a-e10b-4894-af7d-93ba6adf7a1e",
          "args": { "project_id": 176637191, "content": "Task2" } },
      ]'
```

I've tried the following with little luck

```
commands = [{"type": "item_add", "uuid": "a3aa2f44-23b4-4986-b513-ef7663bbb752", "args": {"project_id": 2159935681,"content":"Test Task"}}]
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'https://en.todoist.com/api/v7/sync/',
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      data: {
        'token': todoist_api_token,
        'sync_token':'*',
        'resource_types':'["projects", "items"]',
        'commands':commands
      }
    })
```

I've also tried the following:

```
commands = [{"type": "item_add", "uuid": "a3aa2f44-23b4-4986-b513-ef7663bbb752", "args": {"project_id": 2159935681,"content":"Test Task"}}]
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'https://en.todoist.com/api/v7/sync/',
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      data: {
        'token': todoist_api_token,
        'sync_token':'*',
        'resource_types':'["projects", "items"]',
        'commands':commands
      }
    })
```

This results in the following error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://en.todoist.com/api/v7/sync/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

I've also tried removing the project id

```
commands = [{"type": "item_add", "uuid": "a3aa2f44-23b4-4986-b513-ef7663bbb752", "args": {"content":"Test Task"}}]
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'https://en.todoist.com/api/v7/sync/',
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      data: {
        'token': todoist_api_token,
        'sync_token':'*',
        'resource_types':'["items"]',
        'commands':commands
      }
    })
```

I've also tried adding the temp_id parameter:

```
commands = [{"type": "item_add","temp_id": "fdef5d16-a40a-475e-bd4a-0ccbd6fd8c3f", "uuid": "a3aa2f44-23b4-4986-b513-ef7663bbb752", "args": {"project_id": 2159896038,"content":"Test Task"}}]
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'https://en.todoist.com/api/v7/sync/',
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      data: {
        'token': todoist_api_token,
        'sync_token':'*',
        'resource_types':'["projects", "items"]',
        'commands':commands
      }
    })
```

I've even tried the todoist api v8 version following the todoist instrucitons for the v8 api [here](https://developer.todoist.com/rest/v8/#create-a-new-task)

```
$.ajax({type: "POST",
    url: 'https://beta.todoist.com/API/v8/tasks',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data: {'token':todoist_api_token,'content': 'Appointment with Maria'}
    });
```

This returns "Bad Request"

I did find that the following works for v6:

```
$.ajax({type: "POST",
    url: 'https://todoist.com/API/v6/add_item',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data: {'token':todoist_api_token,'content': 'Appointment with Maria'}
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**sync_token**

In the first example I see that the sync token is set. It should be `var sync_token = '*'` and after the ajax request you should save the token with `sync_token = response.sync_token;` I see that you realized that in the later examples.

**commands**

The rest looks good but I can't see your commands and I guess the problem comes from there. The commands object has to be stringified with `JSON.stringify(commands)`.

**working example**

I created a working example below. You have to replace the `todoist_api_token = ""` with your token and the project id's in the example task.

```js
// Global variables
 
var todoist_api_token = ""; // Put your token here
var sync_token = "*";

// To get a project id: clicke on a project and look at the url.
// In the example "#project%2F2179064046" you have to remove "#project%2F".
// and the project id is 2179064046

// Run example task after document load

window.onload = function() {
 
 console.log("Add example task to todoist");
  
 var example_tasks = [
    {"content": "Task1", "project_id": 2179064046},
    {"content": "Task2", "project_id": 2179064046}
  ];
  
 todoist_add_tasks_ajax(example_tasks);
 
}

// Functions

todoist_add_tasks_ajax = function(tasks) {
  
 var commands = todoist_tasks_to_commands(tasks);
 
 var data = {
  "token" : todoist_api_token,
  'sync_token' : sync_token,
  'resource_types' : '["projects", "items"]',
  'commands' : commands
 };
 
 jQuery.ajax({
  url: "https://todoist.com/api/v7/sync",
  data: data,
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response) {
   console.log(response);
   sync_token = response.sync_token;
  },
  error: function(response) { 
   console.log(response);
  },
 });
 
}

todoist_tasks_to_commands = function(tasks) {
 
 var commands = [];
 
 tasks.forEach(function(args) {
  
  var temp_commands = {
   "type": "item_add",
   "temp_id": create_guid(),
   "uuid": create_guid(),
   "args": args
  };

  commands.push(temp_commands)

 });
 
 commands = JSON.stringify(commands);
 
 return commands;
 
}

function create_guid() {
  function s4() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
      .toString(16)
      .substring(1);
  }
  return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
    s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}

/*

// Install jQuery

javascript: (function(e, s) {
    e.src = s;
    e.onload = function() {
        jQuery.noConflict();
        console.log("jQuery installed");
    };
    document.head.appendChild(e);
})( document.createElement('script'), 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js')

*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
```